# Smooth units - Equations in smooth numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

A "smooth unit" be integer numbers $u$, $v$, $s$, and $t$ so that:

$$
u \cdot v ^{-1} \equiv t \mod{s}
$$

with u, v, s and t being smooth, i.e. only having prime factors below a chosen bound. One can then "cancel" t (multiply with its inverse) to yield

$$
{u \cdot v^{-1} \over t} \equiv 1 \mod{s}
$$

or

${u \over v\cdot t} \equiv 1 \mod{s}$

or

$$
u - v \equiv s\cdot t
$$

Using a canonical representation of the elements of the multiplicative groups of numbers modulo n, I'm able to produce plenty of such smooth units. I'll just pick a few examples.

$(858201488545035745445-1024656101097842597)*857176832443937902848^{-1}$

Is equivalent to $1$ in every ring of integer numbers modulo some N. Another example is:

$2250284989017799369435-2001248800951606101519 \equiv 2000866852567\cdot 124464148$

The procedure is, in short handwaving speech:

- Pick $s$ smooth
- Compute "discrete logarithms" of all small primes (below the smoothness bound) modulo s.
- Use lattice algorithms to find all "units" (by construction, $(u-v) \equiv 0 \mod s$)
- Raise the primitive roots - so that positive powers go to $u$, negative ones to $v$
- Yield a good (small) $t \equiv {u-v \over s}$
- This $t$ is guaranteed to be small, and thus has a large smooth part.

I cannot exclude $t$ containing a "rough" (non-smooth) part. For example, there is:

$1234202238285647390269-1331755127503174774 \equiv 84932022219\cdot 9761915 \cdot 1487$

$1487$ being not $1000$-smooth.

My question is, if and in what way these equivalences could be of any help regarding index-calculus methods. I'm also still struggling with the multiplicative groups of powers of $2$, or of smooth numbers having a multiplicative group order divisible by powers of $2$ larger than $2$ itself. Any associations would be appreciated.

Comment: u: 43915043207915 - {5: 1, 11: 1, 47: 1, 73: 1, 79: 1, 113: 1, 131: 1, 199: 1}
v: 260960121808811 - {23: 1, 29: 1, 37: 1, 61: 1, 89: 1, 107: 1, 109: 1, 167: 1}
s: 1073545221 - {3: 1, 7: 1, 31: 1, 67: 1, 151: 1, 163: 1}
t: 202176 - {2: 6, 3: 5, 13: 1}
u-v = -217045078600896
s*t = 217045078600896

Comment: u: 723751952342 - {2: 1, 19: 1, 53: 1, 113: 1, 137: 1, 139: 1, 167: 1}
v: 7697248066103 - {29: 1, 31: 1, 47: 1, 71: 1, 89: 1, 127: 1, 227: 1}
s: 405884181 - {3: 1, 43: 1, 97: 1, 163: 1, 199: 1}
t: 17181 - {3: 2, 23: 1, 83: 1}
u-v = -6973496113761
s*t = 6973496113761

Comment: More congruences: https://pastebin.com/ND6qpted